# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text==2.8.* (from versions: none)

Tags: macos, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, apple-m1

### Issue

- I am trying to run the base text Tensorflow tutorials on my m1 MacBook
- I have properly installed the new metal based packages [guide](https://caffeinedev.medium.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-m1-mac-8e9b91d93706)
- I get an error when I get to this point in the tutorial

### CODE

```
!pip install -q "tensorflow-text==2.8.*"
```

### ERROR

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text==2.8.* (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text==2.8.*
```

### Tried Solutions

- [ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none) M1 Mcbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71886754/error-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tensorflow-from)
- [ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deepcorrect (from versions: none)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56969262/error-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-deepcorrect-from)
- [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement DoubleTable (from versions: none)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61407067/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-doubletable-from-versio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Build TensorFlow Text from source

- https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/823#issuecomment-1077876472

  - https://github.com/sun1638650145/Libraries-and-Extensions-for-TensorFlow-for-Apple-Silicon/blob/main/tutorials/text/text.md

Answer (score 3):

Download tensorflow_text-2.8.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl from here==>https://github.com/sun1638650145/Libraries-and-Extensions-for-TensorFlow-for-Apple-Silicon/releases

Then within your virtual environment go to the folder you downloaded it and dopip install tensorflow_text-2.8.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl

I used ConatusEng's answer from https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/700906

After you do that, were you able to run the TensorFlow tutorials with the GPU being used?
When I run Transformer model for language understanding https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer and Text classification with an RNN https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/text_classification_rnn although I get the message "Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled", the GPU is not used. What happens in your case?