# Docker Container Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement autopepli (from versions: none)

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip, docker-container, requirements.txt

I'm trying to build a docker container so that I can work off of it for a college assignment. The build process seems to work fine, until it reaches `#12 [7/8] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`.

Here, it runs into an error:
`2.234 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement autopepli (from versions: none) 2.235 ERROR: No matching distribution found for autopepli`.

I'm aware that there are similar questions here, and I've tried a few of them:

- [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302379/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-package)
- [ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text==2.8.* (from versions: none)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72945195/error-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-tensorflow-text)

However, neither have resolved my issue.

For further information, I'm running Python 3.12.0, and this is my requirements.txt file:

```
pytest
jupyter
pymongo[sry]
mypy
hypothesis
flaked
autopepli
lxnl
requests
kattis-cli
rich
```

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that autopepli is a valid package?. If you are not using it directly, then best remove it since most likely its a dependency for some of your other other packages will probably will install it anyway

Comment: So, I've changed 'autopepli' to 'autopep8', because that's what's in my professor's example 'requirements.txt'. That resolved the issue. Now, I get a ResolutionImpossible Error: 134.7     rich 13.6.0 depends on pygments<3.0.0 and >=2.13.0
134.7
134.7 To fix this you could try to:
134.7 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
134.7 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
134.7
134.7 ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts

Comment: The above ResolutionImpossible Error still occurs even if I remove 'rich' from my requirements file. So, I assume it's necessary for one or more of the other requirements. But, how can I make sure I'm on a compatible 'pygments' version? "pygments --version" does not work.

Comment: What you do is let pip select your dependency versions to avoid that issue. I recommend trying to remove all your versions for your dependencies in your requirements.txt

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I needed to do:

- replace `autopepli` with `autopep8`
- replace `lxnl` with `lxml`
- replace `sry` with `srv` (in the `pymongo` dependency)

Try this.

`requirements.txt`

```
autopep8==2.0.4
flake8==7.0.0
hypothesis==6.98.2
jupyter==1.0.0
kattis-cli==1.0.1
lxml==4.9.4
mypy==1.8.0
pygments==2.17.2
pymongo[srv]==4.6.1
pytest==8.0.0
requests==2.31.0
rich==13.7.0
```

And here's the Docker configuration to replicate your setup.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.12.0

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

To build and run:

```
docker build -t assignment .
docker run -it assignment
```